# How to dispose OdbcConnection while trying to connect

Tags: c#-2.0

I'm having two servers. One online and one hot-standby. I'm only writing to the online server, which is working just fine when both servers are up and running - this requires that I'm able to open a odbcconnection to both servers to check which one i online.

However if one of them is not running, when i try to open the odbcconnection it takes a long time. I've tried to make a timer event that is fired 5 seconds after trying to open an odbcconnection - if the state of the odbcconnection is still connecting I dispose the odbcconnetion. An this is here I'm stuck :(

Does one have any idea how to check if an odbcconnection is possible to open or how to dispose it if it's not able to open within X amount of time?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could open both connections asynchronously. Upon connecting successfully with one connection, dispose the other connection.

Comment: I've done some tests now - .net 2.0 that I'm using does not support OpenAsync method for OdbcConnection.

For each connectionstring I'm not creating a thread that opens the OdbcConnection - so now I open both OdbcConnections at the same time, and I know if one of them is connected. If one of the servers is closed, the state for the OdbcConnection is "Connecting" - I would really like to stop trying to connect.

Any idea? :) - I've tried to close and dispose the OdbcConnection and Abort the thread without any luck :(